# compatibility: ESXi on an HighPoint ssd7101a-1 in a ML370 G6

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant

I have an ML370 G* 6server, and planming now, to go for an storage upgrade. After an first evaluation, I came to the conclusion, that it wouldn't make sense, to use SSDs with the P410i.
So I decided to check if the P410i can handle 4 or 5 TB Sata drives, like the Seagate BarraCuda, and us it and the hot swap for this usage. (Does someone already made experience with such big drives and the P410i controller?)
Because an Sata SSD Raid Controller costs also very much, I thought about an M.2 Raid Controller, but it actually looks like there's not much selection, espacially for older systems like mine.
But I saw there the HighPoint SSD7101A-1, which actually does look like an solid Raid Controller for m.2 SSDs.

Now my main-questions are:
- Will the HighPoint Controller work with my ML370 G6? 
( - Can I configure a raid 10?)
- Will it be useable with ESXi 6.5?
(- Can I install ESXi on it?)

Yeah, you probably ask, why I want to go such an big upgrade, but in my opinion it's not much more exspensive than all the other option I have and on the other hand side, I planning to upgrade the ML370 to an ML350 G8 or so at summer, and shut down three physical PCs while replacing them with Thin Clients.

I did now a lot of exploration trough all those websites, but I didn't get a clear statement. I also wrote HighPoint, VMWare and two shops selling this controller, but none of them answered me so far.

So I thought, I ask here, eventually someone had already tried it. Or at least, you guys can name me an good option.

Greetings 
AN602

*= latest SPP installed, running with 2 X5670 and 144GB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use large disks (2TB+) on an HP Smart Array P410.

Make sure the firmware is up-to-date.

It's not a problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. - Do you know, if when the newest SPP is installed, october 2016, the firmware of the P410 is also on the newest state? Or is there an other firmwareupdate just only for the controller?

Comment: There's nothing newer than what you have.

Comment: Ok, so far so clear, thanks. - Already ordered now som 2,5" 5TB drives. I'm wondering, if they are much slower than the SAS 10k drives.

Answer (score 1):

P410i controller has either 8 or 16 2.5" drive bays or 6 3.5" drive bays. It will support any size (up to 16 exabytes).

> Now my main-questions are: - Will the HighPoint Controller work with my ML370 G6? ( - Can I configure a raid 10?) - Will it be useable with ESXi 6.5? (- Can I install ESXi on it?)

According this server specifications https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04282679.pdf , only SmartArray RAID controllers are supported in initial configuration. P410i supports RAID 1+0.  I would suggest asking HP support about working with third-party hardware controllers. ESXi can be installed on any type of the controller.

> Yeah, you probably ask, why I want to go such an big upgrade, but in my opinion it's not much more exspensive than all the other option I have and on the other hand side, I planning to upgrade the ML370 to an ML350 G8 or so at summer, and shut down three physical PCs while replacing them with Thin Clients.
>   I did now a lot of exploration trough all those websites, but I didn't get a clear statement. I also wrote HighPoint, VMWare and two shops selling this controller, but none of them answered me so far.
>   So I thought, I ask here, eventually someone had already tried it. Or at least, you guys can name me an good option.

The best option here will be update the new generation of server and use hardware which is in Hardware compatibility list.

For ML370g6 - http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04282679.pdf

For ML350G8 - https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04128239.pdf (tower)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. - The possibilitys in view on the amount of disks of the controller were already clear for me, it was about the amount of space per disk, because I remember, there was a time, where the 3TB HDDs came on the market, and some mainboards and also professionell raid controller weren't able to handle them.